# playframework2 and Scala - how to launch tests from IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, integration-testing

I got [computer-database](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/resources/manual/gettingStarted/images/computerdatabase.png) application from playframework2's example folder:

1. cd computer-database
2. play
3. test

Got: **All test passed**. (What's is ok)

But when try to launch those tests in IntelliJ IDEA:

1. cd computer-database
2. play idea
3. open project from idea
4. right mouse click on ModelSpec, then -> Run 'Model Spec' and got message **"There is no started application java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application"**
5. if: play run (rinning application), then got: **Cache play already exists
   net.sf.ehcache.ObjectExistsException: Cache play already exists**
6. if go to localhost:9000 to make everything be compiled, applying evolution script then got (again):**There is no started application java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application**

Question is: How to launch these tests from IDEA?

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove the play-source jar from IDEAs classpath.

You find it under "project strucure -> Libraries"

Comment: Thank you, that did it for me, select the play library and remove the -sources.jar from Classes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same problem with **Cache play already exists net.sf.ehcache.ObjectExistsException: Cache play already exists** error.
I don't have good solution for it, but I managed to workaround it by adding `ehcacheplugin=disabled` to `application.conf` file. That solved the problem for now.

Comment: I disabled the ehcacheplugin and it solved the cache problem for me but then I found instead that my unit tests would not update records! Creating new records is fine, but updating them with save() or update() has no effect so I had to re-enable the ehcacheplugin again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it came from the fact that either:

- play was twice in the classpath (2.1 and 2.0.4)
- or ehcache itseld was there twice.

So in both situation, the problem could be solved by checking the `dependencies` report for duplicates and adding `notTransitive()` to the dependencies (in your sbt or .scala file) that are importing other versions.

Note: `notTransitive()` will remove all transitive resolutions, you might use `exclude("<def>")` to narrow the transitive resolution by excluding only some of them -- exhaustively.